# mysqli prepared insert statement not functioning

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have just decided to alter all my queries to prepared statements. A grueling task as I am sure you are aware. Anyway, I have an insert statement that is just not functioning. Nothing is being inserted into the table!

```
       if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO session_id (ID, email, session_ID) VALUES (?,?,?)")){
           $stmt->bind_param('sss', $user_ID, $email, $session_id);
           $stmt->execute();
           setcookie('NBS_ID', $session_id , time()+3600*24*30,'/','');
           $stmt->close();
       }
```

I have tried testing for errors with `$mysqli` and `$stmt` but no error are registering. I have manually entered the SQL into the table and it works so I am completely baffled. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show how you test for errors?

Comment: Output some trace information inside the IF block. Does it actually execute?

Comment: Do you need to bind ID as a string, as opposed to an integer?

Comment: What does `$stmt->execute();` return?

Comment: @aspiringCodingArtisan absolutely nothing!

Comment: @Andrewsi ID is bound as a string

Comment: @nbs189: As per the documentation, `$stmt->execute();` should either return `true` or `false`. By `nothing` do you mean `false`?

Comment: @nbs189 - is it an integer in the database, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix and I am sorry for bothering you with my stupidity on this. I had forgotten to close `$stmt` in a previous statement.